# Como impedir que links ancorados deixem históricos armazenados

Tags: html, css

Tenho um código que possui dois blocos nas laterais e ao clicar neles acontece uma mudança de cor de fundo da página, mas como eles são definidos com 'target' que puxam cada elemento de forma ordenada, acontece o seguinte, para cada click vai armazenando páginas em branco no histórico do navegador, alguém teria alguma solução para impedir esse armazenamento no histórico ao clicar nos blocos?? talvez um javascript ?

```css
body{background-color:#6C9;}

*{ padding:0px; margin:0px;}
.menu{ overflow:hidden;  
}
/*Coloração do background*/
#bc1{ background-color:#6C9;
width:100%; 
position: absolute; 
z-index:-1; 
height:100%; 
left:0px; 
right:0px; 
top:0px; 
display:none; 
}
#bc2{ background-color:#00F;
width:100%; 
position: absolute; 
z-index:-1; 
height:100%; 
left:0px; 
right:0px; 
top:0px; 
display:none; 
}
#bc3{ background-color:#000;
width:100%; 
position: absolute; 
z-index:-1; 
height:100%; 
left:0px; 
right:0px; 
top:0px; 
display:none; 
}
 
/*CFG: cubos-red*/
.menu .pre_nxt{ position:absolute; 
z-index:99; 
top:45%; 
width:100%; 
height:0px;
left:0px;
}
.menu .pre_nxt a{ background-color:#F33; 
position:absolute; 
width:60px; 
height:60px;  
opacity:0.7; 
transition:all 0.3s linear;
}
.menu .pre_nxt a+a{ background-color:#F33; 
left:auto;  
right:0px;
}
.menu .pre_nxt a:hover{ opacity:1;
}
.menu .pre_nxt > div+div{ visibility:hidden;
}

/* visibilidade dos cubos red a cada click*/
.menu >s:target ~ .pre_nxt > *{ visibility:hidden;}
#bk1:target ~ .pre_nxt > *:nth-child(1){ visibility:visible;}
#bk2:target ~ .pre_nxt > *:nth-child(2){ visibility:visible;}
#bk3:target ~ .pre_nxt > *:nth-child(3){ visibility:visible;}


/*Transição ancorada ao clicar nos cubos, cor background aciona */
#bk1:target ~ #bc1{ display:block; }
#bk2:target ~ #bc2{ display:block; }
#bk3:target ~ #bc3{ display:block; }
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
<s id="bk1"></s>
<s id="bk2"></s>
<s id="bk3"></s>

<div id="bc1"></div><!--verde-->
<div id="bc2"></div><!--azul-->
<div id="bc3"></div><!--preto-->


<div class="pre_nxt">
  <div><a href="#bk3"></a><a href="#bk2"></a></div>
  <div><a href="#bk1"></a><a href="#bk3"></a></div>
  <div><a href="#bk2"></a><a href="#bk1"></a></div>
</div>

</nav>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[`location.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)** com `preventDefault()` desta forma:

```
var ancs = document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='#']");

for(var x=0; x<ancs.length; x++){
   ancs[x].onclick = function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      location.replace(this.href);
   }
}
```

Isso irá impedir que o navegador adicione uma nova entrada no `history` cancelando o evento `click` e irá aplicar a âncora `#` contido no `href`.

**Usando jQuery:**

```
$("a[href^='#']").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   location.replace(this.href);
});
```

**[Teste aqui](http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/stack/t9.php)**

Comment: Rapaz, se manja dos paranauê hein. Cara conta pra gente a fonte do seu conhecimento em Javascript, please. :)

Comment: rss.. Não sei muito não. Vou aprendendo estudando e errando tb. :)

Comment: Realmente ele manja mesmo!, queria muito aprender assim como ele e pretendo chegar lá, abençoe meu cérebro e minha lógica meu Deus  kkkk não só a minha mas as do que persistem no JS